# Remove duplicate JSX elements | React Strapi graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, mapping, filtering, strapi

Long story short, i have and array of JSX elements, that looks something like this:

```
              <ChatListCard
                key={index}
                prop1={prop1}
                prop2={prop2}
                prop3={prop3}
              />
```

I get the props for these "Cards" from two different tables in Strapi/Graphql API, so I do something like this:

```
[].concat(
  array1.map((item,index)=> <Card key={index} prop1={item.prop1} ... />),
  array2.map((item,index)=> <Card key={index} prop1={item.prop1} ... />)
)
```

The problem is that array1 and array2 contain some "items" that are identical, and need to be filtered out. Is there a way to do it, using JS:

```
[].concat(...).filter((magic)=> magic but filtered) //use the filter here
```

, or i should do it in GraphQL.
(I have already used *where* clause in there to filter out only the items that I do not need)

```
query ProposalsAndRequests($input:String!){
  proposals(where: {_or:[
    {owner:{email:$input}}
    {task:{owner:{email:$input}}}
  ]},sort:"created_at:desc"){
    id
    ...
    }
  }
  chatRequests(where:{_or:[
    {users_permissions_user:{email:$input}}
    {task:{owner:{email:$input}}}
  ]},sort:"created_at:desc"){
    id
    ...
  }
}
```

- *note: chatRequests and Proposals contain identical fields, they just serve different purposes elsewhere in the site*
- *the users_permissions_user and owner are also the same relation*

Comment: Did you solve your problem? :-)

Comment: hey! still trying to do it.. the set method seems to work to some extend,but does not do the job, but i think i will try the complex filter with reduce if i ever figure out how i works :D

Comment: Check my updated answer for a perhaps more simple to understand solution that does not require reducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the "Set" datastructure in js. `const set = new Set(arr);`. Sets cant have duplicates! :-) but they can have identical objects if the references are not the same.

For a more complex filter, use .reduce function to accumilate only uniques.

Or, you could remove the duplicates by bruteforce it with something like:

```
const noDubs = [];

myArr.foreach(item => {
  if(!noDubs.some(entry = entry.special.property === item.special.property) noDubs.push(item);
});
```